# How do I model Child belongs to class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
create_table "children", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "dob"
    t.string   "child_class"
    t.string   "section"
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

This is the schema I have for the `Child model`. child_class values are getting stored as "1", "2" .. "12".

Should I need to create 12 different models, from Class1 to Class12 and all will have belongs_to Child class? Is there an efficient way to to do this?

Comment: i think polymorphic association sits well here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to achieve? What kind of connection and its purpose? Do you really need 12 different classes, or you can use single Class and enriched many-to-many table, e.g. with "connection type" or whatever field

Comment: As you can see from the schema, the child_class is the data ranging from 1 .. 12. So I have to query the table if I have to find the children of class 10 using where `Child.where(class: [11])`. Instead I think it would be better to have a straight forward relation Class11.children. For that I asked, should I create all the models like Class1, Class2 etc. What do you think?